# which is faster between translateX and translate3d(x,0,0)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm learning browser rendering to understand render process and event loop. I always thought translate3d is faster by GPU render with new layer.

today I test in chrome watching by Performance tool tab. find below:

[translate3d used 105ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObAvt.png)
[translateX only 49ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJZIK.png)

```
@keyframes move {
        100% {
          transform: translateX(300px);
        }
      }
```

```
@keyframes move3d {
        100% {
          transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think your question is clear...what do you want to know?

Comment: maybe you can click two image links ，my images cannot show directly。the images show translateX is faster render than translate3d to move 300px